# Codeigniter email function fails to send rendered html code in yahoo and livemail

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, email

We use the CI mail library in our codeigniter site. It sends emails in proper format in gmail, but in hotmail and yahoo it just shows the html code

we call the html template in file with this:

emailer_temp.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Registration Confirmation Letter</title>

    <style><body>
      <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="background:rgb(233, 234, 234) none repeat scroll 0% 0% / auto padding-box border-box;"><tbody><tr><td><div style="margin:0 auto;width:1089px;padding:0px">
                <table class="main mce-item-table" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" data-types="background,padding,border-radius,image-settings" data-last-type="image-settings">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" class="image image-full element-content element-contenteditable active"  style="padding:0;">
                               <img class="content-image " style="width: 1089px; height: 287px;" src="<?=base_url()."assets/emailer/register.png";?>">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

call template in controller

```
if($ResponseCode=="0"){
            if(checkonlinepayment($MerchantRefNo,$Amount)==1){
            $data->user = $this->user_model->get_user_profile($userid);
            $data->accuser = $this->user_model->get_user_accommodation($userid);
            $data->userpayacc = $this->user_model->get_paydataacc($PaymentID);
            $this->sendtomail($data->user[0]->email,"Registration Confirmation Letter",$data,"emails/emailer_temp.php");
            $mobileno = $data->user[0]->mobileno;
            $this->sendacctosms($mobileno);
            }
        }
```

use sendtomail function in controller

```
function sendtomail($userEmail,$subject,$data,$templates){
        $config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.mysite.com';
        $config['smtp_port'] = '25'; 
        $config['smtp_timeout'] = '1'; 
        $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'tls';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'support@mysite.com';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'admin!@#321';
        $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['priority'] = '1';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('email',$config); 
        $this->email->from('support@mysite.com', '2018');
        $list = array($userEmail, 'mysite@gmail.com', 'mysite@mysite.in');
        $this->email->to($list);
        //$this->email->to($userEmail); // replace it with receiver mail id
        $this->email->subject($subject);

        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8'); //must add this line
        $this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html'); //must add this line

        $body = $this->load->view($templates,$data,true);
        $this->email->message($body); 
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
        $this->email->send();

      }
```

So the question is: why is this code sending the html code as text instead of a rendered message in Yahoo and Hotmail? It works with gmail!

Answer (score 0):

most likely it is a `$this->email->set_header()` problem

you are using:

```
$this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8');
```

**note**: you are using a semi-colon `';'` within your MIME declaration.

it should be:

```
$this->email->set_header('MIME-Version=1.0', 'charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: i do same $this->email->set_header('MIME-Version=1.0', 'charset=utf-8'); but still same error,not get any solution !